# Jquery improvement with multiple accordion in one place

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this following Jquery accordion profile cards of three users, which i want to use on some pages. 
but the problem is the all accordion are collapse when i am trying expend any one of these, as you can see in snippet.

I have a weak Jquery side so honestly i am unable to fix this. kindly help.

```js
$(function(){
 Profile.load();
});

Profile = {
 load:function(){
  this.links();
  this.social();
  this.accordion();
 },
 links:function(){
  $('a[href="#"]').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
  });
 },
 social:function(){
  $('.accordion .about-me .photo .photo-overlay .plus').click(function(){
   $('.social-link').toggleClass('active');
   $('.about-me').toggleClass('blur');
  });
  $('.social-link').click(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass('active');
   $('.about-me').toggleClass('blur');
  });
 },
 accordion:function(){
  var subMenus = $('.accordion .sub-nav').hide();
  $('.accordion > a').each(function(){
   if($(this).hasClass('active')){
    $(this).next().slideDown(100);
   }
  });
  $('.accordion > a').click(function(){
   $this = $(this);
   $target =  $this.closest();
   $this.siblings('a').removeAttr('class');
   $this.addClass('active');
   if(!$target.hasClass('active')){
    subMenus.removeClass('active').slideUp(100);
    $target.addClass('active').slideDown(100);
   }
   return false;
  });
 }
}
```

```css
body{
 margin:0;
 padding: 0;
 color:#444;
 background:#C5E0EF;
 font:400 16px/18px Roboto, sans-serif;
}
*,:after,:before{box-sizing:border-box}
.pull-left{float:left}
.pull-right{float:right}
.clearfix:after,.clearfix:before{content:'';display:table}
.clearfix:after{clear:both;display:block}

.accordion{
 width:100%;
  float:left;
 margin:auto;
 max-width:280px;
 border-radius:3px;
 background:#B7AFA3;
 box-shadow:0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.19),0 12px 15px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.24);
}
.accordion>a{
 color:#374046;
 padding:15px;
 display:block;
 text-decoration:none;
 -webkit-transition:all .3s ease-in-out 0s;
         transition:all .3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.accordion>a:not(:last-child){
 border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
.accordion>a:hover,
.accordion>a.active{
 background:#E8D0A9;
}
.accordion>a.active{
 color:#B77F24;
}
.accordion>a>.alert-numb,
.accordion>.sub-nav>a>.alert-numb{
 color:#eee;
 right:10px;
 height:22px;
 min-width:40px;
 font-size:12px;
 font-weight:600;
 line-height:22px;
 border-radius:15px;
 text-align:center;
 background:#665e51;
}
.accordion>a.active>.alert-numb,
.accordion>.sub-nav>a.active>.alert-numb{
 background:#d0a051;
}
.accordion .sub-nav{
 display:none;
 color:#374046;
 overflow:hidden;
 background:#ecf0f1;
}
.accordion .sub-nav.open{
 display:block;
}
.accordion .sub-nav a{
 display:block;
 color:inherit;
 font-weight:300;
 padding:10px 15px;
 text-decoration:none;
 -webkit-transition:all .2s ease-in-out 0s;
         transition:all .2s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.accordion .sub-nav a:not(:last-child){
 border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}
.accordion .sub-nav a:hover{
 background:#c2ced1;
 box-shadow:5px 0 0 #8ca3a8 inset;
}

.accordion .html{
 padding:15px;
}
.accordion .about-me{
 text-align:center;
 position:relative;
}
.accordion .about-me h4{
 margin-bottom:0;
}
.accordion .about-me p{
 font-size:14px;
 font-weight:300;
 margin-bottom:0;
}
.accordion .about-me .photo{
 width:95px;
 height:95px;
 margin:auto;
 overflow:hidden;
 border-radius:50%;
 position:relative;
 border:4px solid #fff;
 box-shadow:0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.19),0 8px 17px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
 background:url(https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/16630278?v=3&s=460) no-repeat center;
 background-size: cover;
}
.accordion .about-me .photo .photo-overlay{
 top:0;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 bottom:0;
 opacity:0;
 visibility:hidden;
 position:absolute;
 background:rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
.accordion .about-me .photo .photo-overlay .plus{
 top:50%;
 left:50%;
 width:30px;
 height:30px;
 color:#1a1a1b;
 cursor:pointer;
 font-size:24px;
 font-weight:100;
 margin-top:-15px;
 margin-left:-15px;
 position:absolute;
 line-height:30px;
 border-radius:50%;
 text-align:center;
 background:#e8d0a9;
 -webkit-transform:scale(0) rotate(0);
     -ms-transform:scale(0) rotate(0);
         transform:scale(0) rotate(0);
 -webkit-transition:all .1s ease-in-out 0s;
         transition:all .1s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.accordion .about-me .photo:hover .photo-overlay{
 opacity:1;
 visibility:visible;
}
.accordion .about-me .photo:hover .photo-overlay .plus{
 -webkit-transform:scale(1) rotate(90deg);
     -ms-transform:scale(1) rotate(90deg);
         transform:scale(1) rotate(90deg);
}

.accordion .about-me .social-link{
 top:0;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 bottom:0;
 opacity:0;
 padding-top:48px;
 visibility:hidden;
 position:absolute;
 background:rgba(0,0,0,.3);
 -webkit-transition:opacity .5s ease-in-out 0s;
         transition:opacity .5s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.accordion .about-me .social-link.active{
 opacity:1;
 visibility:visible;
}
.accordion .about-me .social-link .link{
 width:30px;
 padding:0;
 color:#eee;
 height:30px;
 margin:0 4px;
 line-height:28px;
 border-radius:50%;
 display:inline-block;
 -webkit-transform:translateY(-80px) scale(0);
     -ms-transform:translateY(-80px) scale(0);
         transform:translateY(-80px) scale(0);
 border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
.accordion .about-me .social-link .link-twitter{
 background:#55acce;
}
.accordion .about-me .social-link .link-codepen{
 background:#1a1a1b;
}
.accordion .about-me .social-link .link-facebook{
 background:#3b5998;
}
.accordion .about-me .social-link .link-dribbble{
 background:#ea4c89;
}
.accordion .about-me .social-link .link:hover{
 box-shadow:none;
}
.accordion .about-me .social-link.active .link{
 -webkit-transform:translateY(0) scale(1);
     -ms-transform:translateY(0) scale(1);
         transform:translateY(0) scale(1);
}
.accordion .about-me .social-link.active .link:nth-child(1){
 -webkit-transition-duration:.1s;
         transition-duration:.1s;
}
.accordion .about-me .social-link.active .link:nth-child(2){
 -webkit-transition-duration:.2s;
         transition-duration:.2s;
}
.accordion .about-me .social-link.active .link:nth-child(3){
 -webkit-transition-duration:.3s;
         transition-duration:.3s;
}
.accordion .about-me .social-link.active .link:nth-child(4){
 -webkit-transition-duration:.4s;
         transition-duration:.4s;
}
.accordion .about-me .social-link.active .link:nth-child(5){
 -webkit-transition-duration:5s;
         transition-duration:5s;
}
.accordion .about-me.blur p,
.accordion .about-me.blur h4,
.accordion .about-me.blur .photo{
 -webkit-filter:blur(2px);
 filter:blur(2px);
}

.accordion .chat .user:not(:last-child){
 margin-bottom:10px;
}
.accordion .chat .user .photo{
 width:40px;
 height:40px;
 font-size:24px;
 line-height:36px;
 text-align:center;
 position:relative;
 border-radius:3px;
 display:inline-block;
 border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
.accordion .chat .user .photo:before,
.accordion .chat .user .photo:after{
 content:'';
 opacity:0;
 visibility:hidden;
 position:absolute;
 -webkit-transition:opacity .4s ease-in-out 0s;
         transition:opacity .4s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.accordion .chat .user .photo:before{
 left:50%;
 width:60px;
 bottom:50px;
 padding:4px;
 font-size:12px;
 line-height:14px;
 margin-left:-30px;
 text-align:center;
 background:#333333;
 border-radius:4px;
 word-break:break-all;
 content:attr(data-username);
}
.accordion .chat .user .photo:after{
 left:50%;
 bottom:35px;
 margin-left:-8px;
 border:8px solid transparent;
 border-top:8px solid #333333;
}
.accordion .chat .user .photo:hover:before,
.accordion .chat .user .photo:hover:after{
 opacity:1;
 visibility:visible;
}

.accordion .chat .user.user-dribble .photo{
 color:#fff;
 margin-right:5px;
 background:#f15e95;
}
.accordion .chat .user .text-msg{
 max-width:70%;
 font-size:13px;
 padding:4px 8px;
 background:#fff;
 border-radius:4px;
 display:inline-block;
 border:1px solid #cdd6d8;
}
.accordion .chat .user.user-khadkamhn .text-msg{
 background:#dce2e4;
}

.accordion .invite{
 text-align:center;
}
.accordion .invite .dribbble{
 display:block;
 color:#c33269;
 margin:10px 0;
 font-size:24px;
 font-family:Pacifico;
}
.accordion .invite .btn{
 color:#eee;
 font-weight:500;
 background:#ccc;
 padding:10px 15px;
 border-radius:2px;
 background:#f15e95;
 display:inline-block;
 text-transform:uppercase;
}
.accordion .invite .btn:hover{
 box-shadow:none;
 background:#cb386f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion-wrap">
 <div class="accordion">
  <a href="#" class="active"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Profile</a>
  <div class="sub-nav active">
   <div class="html about-me">
    <div class="photo">
     <div class="photo-overlay">
      <span class="plus">+</span>
     </div>
    </div>
    <h4>@gautamjhaofficial.in</h4>
    <p>Hi, my name is Gautam Jha</p>
    <div class="social-link">
     <a class="link link-twitter" href="https://twitter.com/__GAUTAMJHA__" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
     <a class="link link-codepen" href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-codepen"></i></a>
     <a class="link link-facebook" href="http://facebook.com/gautamjhaofficial.in" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
     <a class="link link-dribbble" href="http://gautamjhaofficial.in" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i>Chat</a>
  <div class="sub-nav">
   <div class="html chat">
    <div class="user user-khadkamhn clearfix">
     <span class="text-msg pull-right">Sup, how is it going?</span>
    </div>
    <div class="user user-khadkamhn clearfix">
     <span class="text-msg pull-right">Just great, man!</span>
    </div>
    <div class="user user-dribble clearfix">
     <span class="photo pull-left" data-username="dribbble"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></span>
     <span class="text-msg">Cool.</span>
    </div>
    <div class="user user-dribble clearfix">
     <span class="photo pull-left" data-username="dribbble"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></span>
     <span class="text-msg">C U Around</span>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Messages <span class="pull-right alert-numb">12</span></a>
  <div class="sub-nav">
   <a href="#">Inbox<span class="pull-right alert-numb">7</span></a>
   <a href="#">Bookmarks <span class="pull-right alert-numb">5</span></a>
   <a href="#">Sent</a>
   <a href="#">Drafts</a>
   <a href="#">Deleted</a>
   <a href="#">All messages</a>
  </div>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i> Dribbble subscription</a>
  <div class="sub-nav">
   <div class="html invite">
    <p>Follow me in  <span class="dribbble">dribbble</span> network</p>
    <p>Have you subscribed?</p>
    <a class="btn" href="#" target="_blank">Subscribe</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
  
  <div class="accordion-wrap">
 <div class="accordion">
  <a href="#" class="active"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Profile</a>
  <div class="sub-nav active">
   <div class="html about-me">
    <div class="photo">
     <div class="photo-overlay">
      <span class="plus">+</span>
     </div>
    </div>
    <h4>@gautamjhaofficial.in</h4>
    <p>Hi, my name is Gautam Jha</p>
    <div class="social-link">
     <a class="link link-twitter" href="https://twitter.com/__GAUTAMJHA__" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
     <a class="link link-codepen" href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-codepen"></i></a>
     <a class="link link-facebook" href="http://facebook.com/gautamjhaofficial.in" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
     <a class="link link-dribbble" href="http://gautamjhaofficial.in" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i>Chat</a>
  <div class="sub-nav">
   <div class="html chat">
    <div class="user user-khadkamhn clearfix">
     <span class="text-msg pull-right">Sup, how is it going?</span>
    </div>
    <div class="user user-khadkamhn clearfix">
     <span class="text-msg pull-right">Just great, man!</span>
    </div>
    <div class="user user-dribble clearfix">
     <span class="photo pull-left" data-username="dribbble"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></span>
     <span class="text-msg">Cool.</span>
    </div>
    <div class="user user-dribble clearfix">
     <span class="photo pull-left" data-username="dribbble"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></span>
     <span class="text-msg">C U Around</span>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Messages <span class="pull-right alert-numb">12</span></a>
  <div class="sub-nav">
   <a href="#">Inbox<span class="pull-right alert-numb">7</span></a>
   <a href="#">Bookmarks <span class="pull-right alert-numb">5</span></a>
   <a href="#">Sent</a>
   <a href="#">Drafts</a>
   <a href="#">Deleted</a>
   <a href="#">All messages</a>
  </div>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i> Dribbble subscription</a>
  <div class="sub-nav">
   <div class="html invite">
    <p>Follow me in  <span class="dribbble">dribbble</span> network</p>
    <p>Have you subscribed?</p>
    <a class="btn" href="#" target="_blank">Subscribe</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
    <div class="accordion-wrap">
 <div class="accordion">
  <a href="#" class="active"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Profile</a>
  <div class="sub-nav active">
   <div class="html about-me">
    <div class="photo">
     <div class="photo-overlay">
      <span class="plus">+</span>
     </div>
    </div>
    <h4>@gautamjhaofficial.in</h4>
    <p>Hi, my name is Gautam Jha</p>
    <div class="social-link">
     <a class="link link-twitter" href="https://twitter.com/__GAUTAMJHA__" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
     <a class="link link-codepen" href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-codepen"></i></a>
     <a class="link link-facebook" href="http://facebook.com/gautamjhaofficial.in" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
     <a class="link link-dribbble" href="http://gautamjhaofficial.in" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i>Chat</a>
  <div class="sub-nav">
   <div class="html chat">
    <div class="user user-khadkamhn clearfix">
     <span class="text-msg pull-right">Sup, how is it going?</span>
    </div>
    <div class="user user-khadkamhn clearfix">
     <span class="text-msg pull-right">Just great, man!</span>
    </div>
    <div class="user user-dribble clearfix">
     <span class="photo pull-left" data-username="dribbble"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></span>
     <span class="text-msg">Cool.</span>
    </div>
    <div class="user user-dribble clearfix">
     <span class="photo pull-left" data-username="dribbble"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></span>
     <span class="text-msg">C U Around</span>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Messages <span class="pull-right alert-numb">12</span></a>
  <div class="sub-nav">
   <a href="#">Inbox<span class="pull-right alert-numb">7</span></a>
   <a href="#">Bookmarks <span class="pull-right alert-numb">5</span></a>
   <a href="#">Sent</a>
   <a href="#">Drafts</a>
   <a href="#">Deleted</a>
   <a href="#">All messages</a>
  </div>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i> Dribbble subscription</a>
  <div class="sub-nav">
   <div class="html invite">
    <p>Follow me in  <span class="dribbble">dribbble</span> network</p>
    <p>Have you subscribed?</p>
    <a class="btn" href="#" target="_blank">Subscribe</a>
      </div>DSADASDASDSS
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to get `sub-nav` and toggle on with `active` class. if it exist than use `slideUp()` else `slideDown()`  Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/of7tufd2/#&togetherjs=2wf7DPvbRK) May it help!

**JS**

```
$(function () {
            Profile.load();
        });

        Profile = {
            load: function () {
                this.links();
                this.social();
                this.accordion();
            },
            links: function () {
                $('a[href="#"]').click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            },
            social: function () {
                $('.accordion .about-me .photo .photo-overlay .plus').click(function () {
                    $('.social-link').toggleClass('active');
                    $('.about-me').toggleClass('blur');
                });
                $('.social-link').click(function () {
                    $(this).toggleClass('active');
                    $('.about-me').toggleClass('blur');
                });
            },
            accordion: function () {
                var subMenus = $('.accordion .sub-nav').hide();
                $('.accordion > a').each(function () {
                    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
                        $(this).next().slideDown(100);
                    }
                });
                $('.accordion').find('a').click(function () {
                    $this = $(this);
                    $target = $this.next('div.sub-nav');
                    //$this.siblings('a').removeAttr('class');
                    $this.toggleClass('active');
                    if ($target.hasClass('active')) {
                        $target.slideUp(100);
                    }
                    else {
                        $target.slideDown(100);
                    }
                    $target.toggleClass('active')
                    return false;
                });
            }
        }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="accordion-wrap">
        <div class="accordion">
            <a href="#" class="active"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Profile</a>
            <div class="sub-nav active">
                <div class="html about-me">
                    <div class="photo">
                        <div class="photo-overlay">
                            <span class="plus">+</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <h4>@gautamjhaofficial.in</h4>
                    <p>Hi, my name is Gautam Jha</p>
                    <div class="social-link">
                        <a class="link link-twitter" href="https://twitter.com/__GAUTAMJHA__" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                        <a class="link link-codepen" href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-codepen"></i></a>
                        <a class="link link-facebook" href="http://facebook.com/gautamjhaofficial.in" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                        <a class="link link-dribbble" href="http://gautamjhaofficial.in" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i>Chat</a>
            <div class="sub-nav">
                <div class="html chat">
                    <div class="user user-khadkamhn clearfix">
                        <span class="text-msg pull-right">Sup, how is it going?</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="user user-khadkamhn clearfix">
                        <span class="text-msg pull-right">Just great, man!</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="user user-dribble clearfix">
                        <span class="photo pull-left" data-username="dribbble"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></span>
                        <span class="text-msg">Cool.</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="user user-dribble clearfix">
                        <span class="photo pull-left" data-username="dribbble"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></span>
                        <span class="text-msg">C U Around</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Messages <span class="pull-right alert-numb">12</span></a>
            <div class="sub-nav">
                <a href="#">Inbox<span class="pull-right alert-numb">7</span></a>
                <a href="#">Bookmarks <span class="pull-right alert-numb">5</span></a>
                <a href="#">Sent</a>
                <a href="#">Drafts</a>
                <a href="#">Deleted</a>
                <a href="#">All messages</a>
            </div>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i> Dribbble subscription</a>
            <div class="sub-nav">
                <div class="html invite">
                    <p>Follow me in  <span class="dribbble">dribbble</span> network</p>
                    <p>Have you subscribed?</p>
                    <a class="btn" href="#" target="_blank">Subscribe</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="accordion">
            <a href="#" class="active"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Profile</a>
            <div class="sub-nav active">
                <div class="html about-me">
                    <div class="photo">
                        <div class="photo-overlay">
                            <span class="plus">+</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <h4>@gautamjhaofficial.in</h4>
                    <p>Hi, my name is Gautam Jha</p>
                    <div class="social-link">
                        <a class="link link-twitter" href="https://twitter.com/__GAUTAMJHA__" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                        <a class="link link-codepen" href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-codepen"></i></a>
                        <a class="link link-facebook" href="http://facebook.com/gautamjhaofficial.in" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                        <a class="link link-dribbble" href="http://gautamjhaofficial.in" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i>Chat</a>
            <div class="sub-nav">
                <div class="html chat">
                    <div class="user user-khadkamhn clearfix">
                        <span class="text-msg pull-right">Sup, how is it going?</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="user user-khadkamhn clearfix">
                        <span class="text-msg pull-right">Just great, man!</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="user user-dribble clearfix">
                        <span class="photo pull-left" data-username="dribbble"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></span>
                        <span class="text-msg">Cool.</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="user user-dribble clearfix">
                        <span class="photo pull-left" data-username="dribbble"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></span>
                        <span class="text-msg">C U Around</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Messages <span class="pull-right alert-numb">12</span></a>
            <div class="sub-nav">
                <a href="#">Inbox<span class="pull-right alert-numb">7</span></a>
                <a href="#">Bookmarks <span class="pull-right alert-numb">5</span></a>
                <a href="#">Sent</a>
                <a href="#">Drafts</a>
                <a href="#">Deleted</a>
                <a href="#">All messages</a>
            </div>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i> Dribbble subscription</a>
            <div class="sub-nav">
                <div class="html invite">
                    <p>Follow me in  <span class="dribbble">dribbble</span> network</p>
                    <p>Have you subscribed?</p>
                    <a class="btn" href="#" target="_blank">Subscribe</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="accordion">
            <a href="#" class="active"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Profile</a>
            <div class="sub-nav active">
                <div class="html about-me">
                    <div class="photo">
                        <div class="photo-overlay">
                            <span class="plus">+</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <h4>@gautamjhaofficial.in</h4>
                    <p>Hi, my name is Gautam Jha</p>
                    <div class="social-link">
                        <a class="link link-twitter" href="https://twitter.com/__GAUTAMJHA__" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                        <a class="link link-codepen" href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-codepen"></i></a>
                        <a class="link link-facebook" href="http://facebook.com/gautamjhaofficial.in" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                        <a class="link link-dribbble" href="http://gautamjhaofficial.in" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i>Chat</a>
            <div class="sub-nav">
                <div class="html chat">
                    <div class="user user-khadkamhn clearfix">
                        <span class="text-msg pull-right">Sup, how is it going?</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="user user-khadkamhn clearfix">
                        <span class="text-msg pull-right">Just great, man!</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="user user-dribble clearfix">
                        <span class="photo pull-left" data-username="dribbble"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></span>
                        <span class="text-msg">Cool.</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="user user-dribble clearfix">
                        <span class="photo pull-left" data-username="dribbble"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></span>
                        <span class="text-msg">C U Around</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Messages <span class="pull-right alert-numb">12</span></a>
            <div class="sub-nav">
                <a href="#">Inbox<span class="pull-right alert-numb">7</span></a>
                <a href="#">Bookmarks <span class="pull-right alert-numb">5</span></a>
                <a href="#">Sent</a>
                <a href="#">Drafts</a>
                <a href="#">Deleted</a>
                <a href="#">All messages</a>
            </div>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i> Dribbble subscription</a>
            <div class="sub-nav">
                <div class="html invite">
                    <p>Follow me in  <span class="dribbble">dribbble</span> network</p>
                    <p>Have you subscribed?</p>
                    <a class="btn" href="#" target="_blank">Subscribe</a>
                </div>DSADASDASDSS
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you be more clear on how your example may help the OP?

Comment: Definitely I will :)

Comment: Thanks @vispan this is what i am looking for